# Dotcover and Lighthouse produce no report data

Tags: dotcover, lighthouse

I am trying to produce test coverage reports using dotCover and lighthouse.  The dotcover cover command creates a 15Mb .dcvr file, but running dotcover report over that file produces empty results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root Name="Root" CoveredStatements="0" TotalStatements="0" CoveragePercent="0" ReportType="XML" DotCoverVersion="2.0.407.25" />
```

I have successfully produced reports for non silverlight code unit nunit test runner so I know may way around dotCover.

Is anyone aware of any problems using this combination of tools?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment dotCover doesn't provide command line coverage support for Silverlight tests. Thanks for the info, we'll investigate this issue further.

The problem is that a snapshot of the test launcher is taken instead of the process snapshot, and a null result can be caused by the fact that there is no launcher PDB's.